# Initial point of app with shared data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

Here is a structure of my iOS app:

```
                 / NavigationController -> ViewController -> ...
TabBarController - NavigationController -> ViewController -> ...
                 \ NavigationController -> ViewController -> ...
```

TabBarController in the initial point of the app with 3 tabs and then starts navigation throught ViewControllers via NavigationControllers.

I need one place in the app that has access to each ViewController emdedded in NavigationControllers. Lets say it is a controller which is observer for some notifications and sends data to ViewControllers. This controllers also needs to do some operations after starting the app.

My question is where this controller should be placed in the app.  First idea was put all the code into the TabBarController because it is initial point so it can do operations after starting and can access throught NavigationControllers to ViewControllers. But TabBarController is only container so it should not contain additional code which is not relevant to navigation, right?

Next idea is to put ViewController before TabBarController so that ViewController is initial point of the app. On `viewDidLoad` I do some operations which are necessary to do on startup, then register observers for notifications and on `viewDidAppear` I present TabBarController. But problem is when I want to pass data to ViewControllers, these data have to be sent over 2 containers (TabBarController and NavigationController) which seems to be quite complicated.

What do you think? Shall I use TabBarController for this purpose or shall I create new ViewControler as a new initial point? Or shall I use app delagate for it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible solutions. It seems that your controller doesn't even need to be a view controller as its actual responsibility is data.

So, I'd recommend creating a view controller which is basically a duplicate of the launch image, perhaps with a progress indicator, but all it does is sit there and wait - no logic. The logic is in a data controller that it (or the app delegate) triggers. When the logic is done the 'launch VC' gets a callback and pushes to the tab controller.

Now you have a choice about injection, singleton reference or observation about how the data controller communicates with the tabs. If the view controllers don't make requests of the data controller then observation of data events seems like the best option. If they do then injection is likely best.

Comment: So I should create ViewController which has two roles (Launch screen and observer for notifications). Launch screen is visible while the initial code is running. When it is done, ViewController pushes to the TabBarController but even TabBarController is on the top, it still can handle notifications. Correct? Next thing is passing data. Dependency injection is great for my case but how I can pass an object reference to ViewControllers? I have to send the reference to TabBarController, then to NavigationController and then to ViewController?

Comment: Anything can handle notifications. I'd probably tie the launch VC slightly tighter to progress as a delegate rather than using notifications. For injection you would usually pass to the tab controller and then on from there yes (not to the nav controller, you would pass to the navs root controller).

Comment: Actualy when I thinking I do not need the initial code at all. I just need some object that is created after starting the app and this object listen for two system notifications. If it will receive one notification, it sends object reference to VC and if it receive second notification, it sends null. But who should create this object? AppDelegate?

Comment: Yes, that should probably be an app delegate responsibility. If it's that minimal and they are system notifications then it could actually be done by the app delegate itself...

Comment: Yes. they are only two notifications. Problem solved. Thanks.